# Vanilla JS Box Shadow on Scroll

Tags: javascript, css, menu, navigation

I've been learning vanilla JS and most of the solutions to this problem are jquery dependent and I find myself getting a little muddled. (This is not a js over jq argument I am looking for a specific solution).

I am attempting to create a box shadow that activates on a fixed position menu as it scrolls.

If I capture the header element in a variable,

```
var header = document.getElementById("header");
```

and then add the scroll event to it:

```
header.onscroll = function(){};
```

What am I checking for at this point? The y-offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
        document.getElementById("fixedMenu").className = "myFixedMenu-box-shadow";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("fixedMenu").className = "myFixedMenu";
    }
}
```

```css
body{
height: 900px;
}
.myFixedMenu{
width : 100%;
height: 70px;
background-color: black;
position: fixed;}

.myFixedMenu-box-shadow{
  width : 100%;
height: 70px;
background-color: orange;
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<div class="myFixedMenu" id="fixedMenu">
Some Menu Item
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome solution! But why have you passed the function myfunction to the onscroll function? If I just did a window.onscroll = function(){and put the function code here}, would that not work?

Comment: it just for modularity, you can have myFunction code inside onscroll also.

Answer (score 0):

your code is binding to the onscroll event of `header` but based upon what you've explained, you could bind to to the `onscroll` event of the body and check for `window.scrollY`

http://mdn.io/scrollY

Comment: Ah.  So if I make var $content = (window), I just check for if y != 0?